# Geometric interpretation of polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

For example $p_3$ has ${1,t,t^2,t^3}$ bases.
Is their any geometric interpretation for it?
In addition,I have seen that the polynomial function $g(t)$ is considered as a vector! And the sum of two polynomials is the sum of their vectors! How's that possible?
I'm mostly looking for intuition, anything will be helpful regarding the question.

Answer (score 1):

The space of polynomials $P_3(\mathbb K)$ where $\mathbb K$ is a field is a four-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$ with basis $\{1, t, t^2, t^3\}$
Thus it is isomorphic to $\mathbb K^4$ with element-wise addition, the polynomials $\{1, t, t^2, t^3\}$ map to the canonical basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ of unit vectors.
Addition of polynomials is then the same as addition of their images ('vectors'), addition in $\mathbb K^4$ and inversion of this mapping (back to polynomials).

I'm not sure what you would want as a geometric interpretation. Do you have some examples for, say $P_1$ or $P_2$?

Comment: No, i do not have any example but i wanted to know how do we show the basis $t^2$ in coordinate system? For instance we can show $e_1$ in coordinate system.what is canonical basis? And isomorphism? Do not link to wikipedia please, i want simple definition.thanks

Comment: @FreeMind I'm sorry but I can't understand your problem. An Isomorphism is a bijection of wich both sides respect the structure (here only addition) of the domain and image. The canonical basis vectors $e_i = (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots 0)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ defined by $(e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$ should be known to you if you know what a basis is. And "showing" of functions is commonly referred to as plotting.